# Scan time of cache, RAM và disk?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Consider a computer system that has cache memory, main memory (RAM), and disk, and OS uses virtual memory. It takes 2 nsec to access a byte from the cache, 20 nsec to access a byte from RAM, and 10 msec to access a block of 1000 bytes from the disk. If a book has 1000 pages, each with 50 lines of 80 characters each, How long it will take to electronically scan the text for the case of the master copy being in each of the level as one proceeds down the memory hierarchy(from inboard memory to offline storage)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If a book has 1000 pages, each with 50 lines of 80 characters each, then the book has `1000 * 50 * 80 = 4000000` characters. We don't know how big a character is (and it could be UTF8 where different characters are different sizes), we don't know how much meta-data there is (e.g. if it's a word-processor file with extra information in a header about page margins, tab stops; plus more data for which font and style, etc) or if there's any extra processing (e.g. compression of pieces within the file).

If we make an unfounded assumption that the file happens to be 4000000 bytes; then we might say that it'll be 4000 blocks (with 1000 bytes per block) on disk.

Then we get into trouble. A CPU can't access data on disk (and can only access data in RAM or cache); so it needs to be loaded into RAM (e.g. by a disk controller) before the CPU can access it.

If it takes the disk controller 10 msec to access a block of 1000 bytes from disk, then we might say it will take at least `10 msec * 4000 = 40000 msec = 40 seconds` to read the whole file into disk. However this would be wrong - the disk controller (acting on requests by file system support code) will have to find the file (e.g. read directory info, etc), and that the file may be fragmented so the disk controller will need to read (and then follow) a "list of where the pieces of the file are".

Of course while the CPU is scanning the first part of the file the disk controller can be reading the last part of the file; either because the software is designed to use asynchronous IO or because the OS detected a sequential access pattern and started pre-fetching the file before the program asked for it. In other words; the ideal case is that when the disk controller finishes loading the last block the CPU has already scanned the first 3999 blocks and only has to scan 1 more (and the worst case is that disk controller and CPU don't do anything at the same time it becomes "40 seconds to load the file into RAM plus however long it takes for CPU to scan the data in RAM".

Of course we also don't know things like (e.g.) if the file is actually loaded 1 block at a time (if it's split into 400 transfers with 10 blocks per transfer then the "ideal case" would be worse as CPU would have to scan the last 10 blocks after they're loaded and not just the last one block); of how many reads the disk controller does before a pre-fetcher detects that it's a sequential pattern.

Once the file is in RAM we have more problems.

Specifically; anyone that understands how caches work will know that "It takes 2 nsec to access a byte from the cache, 20 nsec to access a byte from RAM" means that when you access one byte in RAM it takes 18 nsec to transfer a cache line (a group of consecutive bytes) from RAM to cache plus 2 nsec to obtain that 1 byte from cache; and then the next byte you access will have already been transferred to cache (as it's part of "group of consecutive bytes") and will only cost 2 nsec.

After the file's data is loaded into RAM by disk controller; because we don't know the cache line size, we don't know how many of software's accesses will take 20 nsec and how many will take 2 nsec.

The final thing is that we don't actually know anything useful about the caches. The general rule is that the larger a cache is the slower it is; and "large enough to contain the entire book (plus the program's code, stack, parts of the OS, etc) but fast enough to have a 2 nsec access times" is possibly an order of magnitude better than any cache that has ever existed. Essentially, the words "the cache" (in the question) can not be taken literally as it would be implausible. If we look at anything that's close to being able to provide a 2 nsec access time we see multiple levels - e.g. a fast and small L1 cache with a slower but larger L2 cache (with an even slower but larger L3 cache). To make sense of the question you must assume that "the cache" meant "the set of caches", and that the L1 cache has an access time of 2 nsec (but is too small to hold the whole file and everything else) and other levels of the cache hierarchy (e.g. L2 cache) have unknown slower access times but may be large enough to hold the whole file (and everything else).

Mostly; if I had to guess; I'd assume that the question was taken from a university course (because universities have a habit of tricking students into paying $$$ for worthless "fictional knowledge").